# Wikipedia data extraction

Tags: sql, wikipedia

I am trying to populate some tables with Hindi Wikipedia data. I have to populate it with article titles, their categories and their corresponding English url.
Right now I am finding the category and English url by parsing the html file and locating the particular div tag. This is taking a lot of time. Is there any direct and efficient way to populate the categories. Do let me know. 
I have downloaded hindi wikipedia from the link: ftp://wikipedia.c3sl.ufpr.br/wikipedia/hiwiki/20131201/

Answer (score 1):

You could either use some sort of parsing engine like Wikiprep: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gabr/resources/code/wikiprep/

Or you could use the MediaWiki engine to handle the Wiki markup language. 
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps

There might be some other options that might be relevant to your case, you can check out also here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Help_importing_dumps_into_MySQL

(I've personally used options #1 and #2)